# Confused in the two differente MSDN documentation (ThreadWaitState)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

My main thread, draws many lines (700-1500) on the screen, when an new event occurs. (~10..100ms)
The main Thread draws but hangs some times (for very long time (30sec-minutes), I don't really understand why.

ThreadWaitState is 2
ThreadWaitReason is 27    (some times 0, 31)

I am confusing in MSDN documentations, there are two differents pages for ThreadState enum.
Very differents enums

- [ThreadState enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?view=net-5.0)
- [ThreadState enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?view=net-5.0)

Which one fits?

Comment: Have a look at [ThreadState enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?view=net-5.0): Remarks: _Important

There are two thread state enumerations, System.Diagnostics.ThreadState and System.Threading.ThreadState. The thread state enumerations are only of interest in a few debugging scenarios. Your code should never use thread state to synchronize the activities of threads._

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?view=net-5.0) is fit - 2 - is *StateRunning*. `KWAIT_REASON` exit sense only in case thread in `StateWait` (5) state.

Comment: You have linked to .NET documentation, but used the [tag:c++] and [tag:mfc] tags. Is this intentional?

Comment: Additonal Info, The ThreadWaitState & ThreadWatReason numbers are  the result from Perfomance Monitor (perfmon.exe) ThreadCounter

Comment: @IInspectable No, I didn't  want a .NET documentation. MS make it difficult to find any documentations without .NET nowaday.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat & RbMm: if the state is in this case 'StateRunning'. My interpretation is then: The MainThread constantly running and draws all the time remaining PostMessage orders from a worker-thread.  (Drawing Time ~70..140ms). To fix, I should limit the PostMessage orders?

Comment: To fix the issue you should probably explain the issue rather than some random observation. A [mcve] goes a long way.

Comment: Solved. The GUI Thread was constantly busy with too many update request (PostMessages) from a worker thread.  I solved this with slow down the update frequency,  draw only the last message, and optimize the code for faster drawing.

Comment: That's a rather heavy-handed approach to solve what the system already solved for you. Simply call `InvalidateRect` from your message handler of those posted messages, and allow the system to automatically coalesce multiple damage regions into a single `WM_PAINT` message. Since you have decided not to ask about your problem you never received an answer.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for the hint. Yes, a simple InvalidateRect would work for a only One CView. But even Invalidate is not enough if you have more than one CView to update. In my case I have also to Update the Statusbar, Toolbars and OutputPanes synchronously. And worrse this problem I have never seen on my Developer PC, only on the machine PC. So I had to guess what the permon.exe will say me with his ThreadWaitState.

Answer (score 0):

[ThreadState Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?view=net-5.0):System.Diagnostics.ThreadState. Specifies the current execution state of the thread.

[ThreadState Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?view=net-5.0):System.Threading.ThreadState. Specifies the execution states of a Thread. The ThreadState enumeration defines a set of all possible execution states for threads.

The namespace of the [ThreadWaitReason Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadwaitreason?view=net-5.0) is `System.Diagnostics`. The [WaitReason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread.waitreason?view=net-5.0) property is valid only when the [ThreadState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_ThreadState_Wait) is Wait. The `ThreadState` is System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.

Comment: This is a copy&paste from MSDN doc. Still not clair for me. The results are watched in the Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe), which WaitingStates & Reason are refereed to? Example ThreadWaitState = 2. SystemDiagnostics says SuspendRequested, SystemThreading says : Running. I am still confused